# Kafka distributing messages from a partition among consumers

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I have a Kafka topic which currently has 3 partitions. I want my consumers to read from the same partition but each message should go to a different consumer in a round-robin fashion. Is it possible to achieve this?

Comment: Do you mean message 1 should go to consumer 1, message 2 to consumer 2, message 3 to consumer 3? This is not possible.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I meant.

Answer (score 0):

In order to do that, you have to implement a consumer group. It's provided out of the box with Kafka. You have just to specify the same group.id to your tree consumer.

[edit] But, each consumers will read in different Kafka partition. I think that make difference consumer for mthe same group read in the same partition is not possible if you're using only the Kafka API.

See more in the documentation : http://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#intro_consumers

Comment: This won't allow multiple consumers consume one partition

Comment: In that case each partition goes to exactly one consumer within the same consumer group.

Answer (score 0):

How about this, at the producer, the messages are routed based on some key. It is possible to route message 1 to partition 1, message 2 to partition 2, message 3 to partition 3. Then you should group three consumers in one group. It is possible to make consumer 1 to consume partition 1, consumer 2 to consume partition 2, consumer 3 to consume partition 3.

By the way, how to implement it depends on which kafka client you are using, what the messages are. You should give more details....

Answer (score 0):

What you are saying defeats the purpose of partitions. Partitions are not designed for simple load balancing in kafka. If you really want that, you have two options.

1. If you have a control over the producer producing to the topic, do a simple mod 3 hash partitioning. So the messages will be distributed equally in the 3 partitions. Now each of your consumer will consume from one partition. This effectively means every third message is read by each consumer. That solves your problem.
2. If you cannot control the producer, consume from the topic in the normal way. Write a producer with simple mod 3 hash partitioning and produce it to a new topic. Again consume from that topic. The same thing repeats as in the first case.